# Is the following set linearly independent or basis of vector space $R^5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following set of vectors:

$v_1 = (1,-2,1,0,0)$

$v_2 = (0,2,3,-5,0)$

$v_3 = (-6,2,2,2,0)$

Let $(e_1,...,e_5)$ be the natural basis for vector space $\mathbb{R}^5$, so that $e_1= (1,0,0,0,0)$ and so on. Denote $S = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

Answer / correct the following claims:

$S\space\cup \{e_5\}$ is linearly independent and/or basis for vector space $\mathbb{R}^5$. My answer: It's linearly independent, but clearly not the basis as there are only four components.

$S\space\cup \{e_4,e_5\}$ is linearly independent and/or basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$. My answer: My answer: According to my calculation they are linearly independent and as such the set forms basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$.

$S\space\cup \{e_3,e_4,e_5\}$ is linearly independent and/or basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$. My answer: clearly there are too many elements to be the basis, and it looks as though it's linearly dependent as well.

We can pick some vector $v_i$, such that $\{v_i,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ forms the basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$. My answer: No, as the fifth element is always zero.

EDIT: One more claim: The fact that the first four elements of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ add up to zero, while $e_4$ adds up to 1, can be used in solving the other questions. This didn't help me, but can the fact be used somewhere?

Comment: what is the question exactly?, Are you just wondering if your homework was correct?

Comment: For your third answer, it is worth pointing out to you that it is impossible to have six linearly independent vectors in a 5-dimensional space, you don't need to actually check linear dependence.

Comment: @mdave16 Yes I am wondering about that indeed.

Comment: seems good, I think you should post an answer to this question with your solutions and a bit more detail on your answers